# How can I loop through multiple unknown number of pages and get their texts after the year is substituted in the url?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some information based on the year entered in the url. The information extracted is from an unknown number of pages.

How can I get the new url after the year is substituted so that this url can be passed for processing the content extracted from multiple pages? Also, I want to be able to get all the information from all the unknown number of pages.

As I understood, I would need a while loop. How do I check if there exists a next page?

Is there an efficient way to do this? Thanks!

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import parse
from time import sleep

input_year = int(input("Enter year here >>: "))

def print_info(response_text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'lxml')
    for info in soup.find_all('div', class_='grid'):
        for a in info.find_all('a'):
            if a.parent.name == 'div':
                print (''.join(text for text in a.find_all(text=True)))

url = 'https://mywebsite.org/archive.pl?op=bytime&keyword=&year={}&page={}'.format(input_year,1)

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

#current page number
page_number_tag = soup.find('span', class_='active tcenter')
page_number = page_number_tag.text

#next page number 
for x in soup.find_all('div', class_='t'):
    for a in x.find_all('a'):
        if a.parent.name == 'div':
            next_page_number = ''.join(text for text in a.find_all(text=True))
```

Comment: What is your input to the script and what  are you expected as output ?

Comment: A URL with a year that has text as its content. But this content is divided into pages. Expecting results from across all pages based on the substituted year in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the variables `year` and `page` already, you can use string formatting to build a new url with those values:

```
base_url = url = 'https://mywebsite.com/archive.pl?op=bytime&keyword=&year=%s&page=%s'
new_url = base_url % (year, page)
```

Comment: You have to provide those yourself.  The question didn't say how those are obtained, so I left it up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `format` and pass multiple arguments like below.This is an example you can specify year and page the way you want.

```
year=2019
for page in range(1,10):
   url = 'https://mywebsite.com/archive.pl?op=bytime&keyword=&year={}&page={}'.format(year,page)
   print(url)
```

Comment: Thanks! Would this work too if there are more than 10 pages?

Comment: Hi! This is only including pages till 9. The number of pages is unknown, is there a way around this?

Comment: You need to use while loop not for and check for next page button not available? inside while loop.

Comment: I have added more code. Could you please check? Not really sure how I could check the conditions for "if there is a next page"

Comment: You have to share url here?